# Problem on Arduino Interrupt and RTC

Tags: arduino-uno, interrupt, rtc

I am doing an experiment. In this experiment I want to start the RTC by presing the external Push Button which is connected with Aquino's pin 2 and take varites of action according to Time. For interrupt I have made a ISR and in this interrupt I wrote my main logic. But this things is not working.
The schematics is[image: Schematic Diagram]

and The code is

```
`include <Wire.h>
#include "RTClib.h"
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

// initialize the library with the numbers of the interface pins
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 9);

RTC_DS1307 rtc;
int k = 0;
int led =13;
int pin =2;

char daysOfTheWeek[7][12] = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};


void setup () {
 lcd.begin(16, 2);
 rtc.begin();
 Serial.begin(11520);
 pinMode(led,OUTPUT);
 pinMode(pin,INPUT);
 attachInterrupt(0, Time  , LOW);
  // Print a message to the LCD.
  if (! rtc.begin()) {
    lcd.print("hello, world!");
    while (1);
}

  if (! rtc.isrunning()) {
    Serial.println("RTC is NOT running!");
  }
}
void loop()
{}

void Time()
   {
    {DateTime now = rtc.now();
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print(now.year(), DEC);
    lcd.print("/");
    lcd.print(now.month(), DEC);
    lcd.print("/");
    lcd.print(now.day(), DEC);
    lcd.print(" ");
    lcd.print(daysOfTheWeek[now.dayOfTheWeek()]);
    int c = now.second();
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print(c);
    if(c==58)
      {
        k=k+1;
        lcd.setCursor(5, 1);
        lcd.print(k);
        if(k==4)
          {
            digitalWrite(led,HIGH);
            k=0;
          }
     }

    }}`
```

please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, for example Arduino's `delay` needs interrupts to be working and as you may not know it's disabled inside of `ISR` handler.

Never ever use anything like `while (1)`, `delay(1000)` and so on inside of `ISR`! And also do not reenable interrupts either! Set a simple `volatile` flag and use it inside of `loop` function instead.

Basically something like this:

```
constexpr int8_t button = 2;
volatile bool      flag = false;

void setFlag() {
  flag = true;
}

void setup() {
  pinMode(button, INPUT_PULLUP);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(button), &setFlag, FALLING);
}

void loop() {
  if (flag) {
    // it's running, you can do something here

    // and you can reset the flag here either
  }
  //delay(100); // if needed
}
```

Comment: sorry I am not getting your point. I have used `while(1)` and `delay()` for special reason forget about that. I have checked this code without `while(1)` `delay()` inside `ISR` still its not working.

Comment: @Prayuktibid: You wrote “_I have checked this code without [...] still its not working._” There is no point in talking about code we cannot see. Please update the question with the relevant code and tell us exactly _how_ it is not working.

Comment: @EdgarBonet  I have updated the code plaese check it

Comment: @KIIV Sir, Why you using address of `setFlag()` Function Instead of `setFlag()` function in this program please explain me.

Comment: @Prayuktibid Well, without ampersand it's converted to the function pointer implicitly, so it's not required. But it's more obvious for reviewers or coworkers. For the class methods (member functions) it's required.